# How to fix lxml assertion error

Tags: python, lxml

I have an ubuntu machine running `pythong.2.7.6`. When I try using lxml, which has been installed using `pip`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./export.py", line 44, in fetch_item
    root.append(elem)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 742, in lxml.etree._Element.append     (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:44339)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 24, in lxml.etree._assertValidNode     (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:14127)
AssertionError: invalid Element proxy at 140443984439416
```

What does this mean, and how should I go about fixing this?

Comment: So what does `root.append(elem)` do in your code? Where does `elem` come from?

Comment: The traceback tells you that whatever you are trying to append is not a valid node. So we'll need to see your code to ascertain what you are trying to do here and how you can fix this.

Comment: Could you please answer @MartijnPieters's question above? Do you use `multiprocessing` module?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in `multiprocessing` context. It can be illustrated by the following snippet:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import lxml.html


def process(html):
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    body = tree.find('.//body')
    print(body)
    return body


def main():
    pool = Pool()
    result = pool.apply(process, ('<html><body/></html>',))
    print(type(result))
    print(result)  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The result of running it is the following output:

```
<Element body at 0x7f9f690461d8>
<class 'lxml.html.HtmlElement'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 14, in main
    print(result)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 1142, in lxml.etree._Element.__repr__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54748)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 992, in lxml.etree._Element.tag.__get__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:53182)
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 19, in lxml.etree._assertValidNode (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:16856)
AssertionError: invalid Element proxy at 139697870845496
```

Thus most obvious explanation, taking into account that `__repr__` works from the worker process and the return value is available to the calling process, is deserialisation issue. It can be solved, for example, by returning `lxml.html.tostring(body)`, or any other `pickle`-able object.

Comment: Yes, lxml cannot be pickled (as for now) so it cannot be transferred between processes by multiprocessing package. See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/736708